# How can I make a slider that automatically moves left to right in iOS?

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm just starting to program games for iOS with Objective-C, and I'm trying to figure out how to make a slider whose thumb moves back and forth at a random speed. I can't find anything online, maybe I just don't know the right term to search for.

Does the UIKit slider have a built in method to make the slider thumb move back and forth without user input, or would I have to write something myself? What I'm trying to do is build a game where the slider moves back and forth slowly at first, then as you get further into the game the thumb moves faster.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are making a game, as you said, using UIKit objects is probably not the way to go as far as UI is concerned. Just my opinion, though.

But if this is what you are looking for: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Good luck!